# Hand-over-hand locking with Rust

Tags: data-structures, locking, rust

I'm trying to write an implementation of [union-find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) in Rust. This is famously very simple to implement in languages like C, while still having a complex run time analysis.

**I'm having trouble getting Rust's mutex semantics to allow iterative hand-over-hand locking.**

Here's how I got where I am now.

First, this is a very simple implementation of part of the structure I want in C:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
  struct node * parent;
};

struct node * create(struct node * parent) {
  struct node * ans = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  ans->parent = parent;
  return ans;
}

struct node * find_root(struct node * x) {
  while (x->parent) {
    x = x->parent;
  }
  return x;
}

int main() {
  struct node * foo = create(NULL);
  struct node * bar = create(foo);
  struct node * baz = create(bar);
  baz->parent = find_root(bar);
}
```

Note that the structure of the pointers is that of an **inverted tree**; multiple pointers may point at a single location, and there are no cycles.

At this point, there is no path compression.

Here is a Rust translation. I chose to use Rust's reference-counted pointer type to support the inverted tree type I referenced above.

Note that this implementation is much more verbose, possibly due to the increased safety that Rust offers, but possibly due to my inexperience with Rust.

```
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Node {
    parent: Option<Rc<Node>>
}

fn create(parent: Option<Rc<Node>>) -> Node {
    Node {parent: parent.clone()}
}

fn find_root(x: Rc<Node>) -> Rc<Node> {
    let mut ans = x.clone();
    while ans.parent.is_some() {
        ans = ans.parent.clone().unwrap();
    }
    ans
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Rc::new(create(None));
    let bar = Rc::new(create(Some(foo.clone())));
    let mut prebaz = create(Some(bar.clone()));
    prebaz.parent = Some(find_root(bar.clone()));
}
```

Path compression re-parents each node along a path to the root every time `find_root` is called. To add this feature to the C code, only two new small functions are needed:

```
void change_root(struct node * x, struct node * root) {
  while (x) {
    struct node * tmp = x->parent;
    x->parent = root;
    x = tmp;
  }
}

struct node * root(struct node * x) {
  struct node * ans = find_root(x);
  change_root(x, ans);
  return ans;
}
```

The function `change_root` does all the re-parenting, while the function `root` is just a wrapper to use the results of `find_root` to re-parent the nodes on the path to the root.

In order to do this in Rust, I decided I would have to use a `Mutex` rather than just a reference counted pointer, since the `Rc` interface only allows mutable access by copy-on-write when more than one pointer to the item is live. As a result, all of the code would have to change. Before even getting to the path compression part, I got hung up on `find_root`:

```
use std::sync::{Mutex,Arc};

struct Node {
    parent: Option<Arc<Mutex<Node>>>
}

fn create(parent: Option<Arc<Mutex<Node>>>) -> Node {
    Node {parent: parent.clone()}
}

fn find_root(x: Arc<Mutex<Node>>) -> Arc<Mutex<Node>> {
    let mut ans = x.clone();
    let mut inner = ans.lock();
    while inner.parent.is_some() {
        ans = inner.parent.clone().unwrap();
        inner = ans.lock();
    }
    ans.clone()
}
```

This produces the error (with 0.12.0)

```
error: cannot assign to `ans` because it is borrowed
ans = inner.parent.clone().unwrap();

note: borrow of `ans` occurs here
let mut inner = ans.lock();
```

What I think I need here is hand-over-hand locking. For the path A -> B -> C -> ..., I need to lock A, lock B, unlock A, lock C, unlock B, ... Of course, I could keep all of the locks open: lock A, lock B, lock C, ... unlock C, unlock B, unlock A, but this seems inefficient.

However, `Mutex` does not offer unlock, and uses RAII instead. **How can I achieve hand-over-hand locking in Rust without being able to directly call `unlock`?**

---

**EDIT**: As the comments noted, I could use `Rc<RefCell<Node>>` rather than `Arc<Mutex<Node>>`. Doing so leads to the same compiler error.

For clarity about what I'm trying to avoid by using hand-over-hand locking, here is a `RefCell` version that compiles but used space linear in the length of the path.

```
fn find_root(x: Rc<RefCell<Node>>) -> Rc<RefCell<Node>> {
    let mut inner : RefMut<Node> = x.borrow_mut();
    if inner.parent.is_some() {
        find_root(inner.parent.clone().unwrap())
    } else {
        x.clone()
    }
}
```

Comment: No, a `Mutex` is almost certainly the wrong choice here. If you stay within a single task, as you probably should (by default), mutating something behind an `Rc` is best done with `Rc<Cell<T>>` (if `T` is `Copy`) or `Rc<RefCell<T>>` (if it's not).

Comment: I agree that a `Cell` or `RefCell` is the right avenue here. You have a method that looks immutable (`find`), but wants to mutate the data behind-the-scenes. That's a prime case for the Cell family.

Comment: When using `Rc<RefCell<Node>>` in place of `Arc<Mutex<Node>>` (and `borrow_mut` in place of `lock`), I get exactly the same error: "error: cannot assign to `ans` because it is borrowed . . ."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can pretty easily do full hand-over-hand locking as we traverse this list using just a bit of `unsafe`, which is necessary to tell the borrow checker a small bit of insight that we are aware of, but that it can't know.

But first, let's clearly formulate the problem:

- We want to traverse a linked list whose nodes are stored as `Arc<Mutex<Node>>` to get the last node in the list
- We need to lock each node in the list as we go along the way such that another concurrent traversal has to follow strictly behind us and cannot muck with our progress.

Before we get into the nitty-gritty details, let's try to write the signature for this function:

`fn find_root(node: Arc<Mutex<Node>>) -> Arc<Mutex<Node>>`;

Now that we know our goal, we can start to get into the implementation - here's a first attempt:

```
fn find_root(incoming: Arc<Mutex<Node>>) -> Arc<Mutex<Node>> {
    // We have to separate this from incoming since the lock must
    // be borrowed from incoming, not this local node.  
    let mut node = incoming.clone();
    let mut lock = incoming.lock();
    
    // Could use while let but that leads to borrowing issues.
    while lock.parent.is_some() {
       node = lock.parent.as_ref().unwrap().clone(); // !! uh-oh !!
       lock = node.lock();
    }

    node
}
```

If we try to compile this, rustc will error on the line marked `!! uh-oh !!`, telling us that we can't move out of node while `lock` still exists, since `lock` is borrowing `node`. This is not a spurious error! The data in `lock` might go away as soon as `node` does - it's only because we know that we can keep the data `lock` is pointing to valid and in the same memory location even if we move `node` that we can fix this.

The key insight here is that the lifetime of data contained within an `Arc` is dynamic, and it is hard for the borrow checker to make the inferences we can about exactly how long data inside an `Arc` is valid.

This happens every once in a while when writing rust; you have more knowledge about the lifetime and organization of your data than rustc, and you want to be able to express that knowledge to the compiler, effectively saying "trust me". Enter: `unsafe` - our way of telling the compiler that we know more than it, and it should allow us to inform it of the guarantees that we know but it doesn't.

In this case, the guarantee is pretty simple - we are going to replace node while lock still exists, but we are not going to ensure that the data inside lock continues to be valid even though node goes away. To express this guarantee we can use `mem::transmute`, a function which allows us to reinterpret the type of any variable, by just using it to change the lifetime of the lock returned by node to be slightly longer than it actually is.

To make sure we keep our promise, we are going to use another handoff variable to hold node while we reassign lock - even though this moves node (changing its address) and the borrow checker will be angry at us, we know it's ok since `lock` doesn't point at node, it points at data inside of `node`, whose address (in this case, since it's behind an `Arc`) will not change.

Before we get to the solution, it's important to note that the trick we are using here is *only* valid because we are using an `Arc`. The borrow checker is warning us of a possibly serious error - if the `Mutex` was held inline and not in an `Arc`, this error would be a correct prevention of a use-after-free, where the `MutexGuard` held in `lock` would attempt to unlock a `Mutex` which has already been dropped, or at least moved to another memory location.

```
use std::mem;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn find_root(incoming: Arc<Mutex<Node>>) -> Arc<Mutex<Node>> {
    let mut node = incoming.clone();
    let mut handoff_node;
    let mut lock = incoming.lock().unwrap();
    
    // Could use while let but that leads to borrowing issues.
    while lock.parent.is_some() {
       // Keep the data in node around by holding on to this `Arc`.
       handoff_node = node;

       node = lock.parent.as_ref().unwrap().clone();

       // We are going to move out of node while this lock is still around,
       // but since we kept the data around it's ok.
       lock = unsafe { mem::transmute(node.lock().unwrap()) };
    }

    node
}
```

And, just like that, rustc is happy, and we have hand-over-hand locking, since the last lock is released only after we have acquired the new lock!

There is one unanswered question in this implementation which I have not yet received an answer too, which is whether the drop of the old value and assignment of a new value to a variable is a guaranteed to be atomic - if not, there is a race condition where the old lock is released before the new lock is acquired in the assignment of `lock`. It's pretty trivial to work around this by just having another `holdover_lock` variable and moving the old lock into it before reassigning, then dropping it after reassigning `lock`.

Hopefully this fully addresses your question and shows how `unsafe` can be used to work around "deficiencies" in the borrow checker when you really do know more. I would still like to want that the cases where you know more than the borrow checker are rare, and transmuting lifetimes is not "usual" behavior.

Using `Mutex` in this way, as you can see, is pretty complex and you have to deal with *many*, *many*, possible sources of a race condition and I may not even have caught all of them! Unless you really need this structure to be accessible from many threads, it would probably be best to just use `Rc` and `RefCell`, if you need it, as this makes things *much* easier.

Comment: Great answer! What interface would `Mutex`/`MutexGuard` have to have to make this possible without the `unsafe` block?

Comment: It's really not possible for `Mutex` to expose an interface that allows this without somehow integrating directly with `Arc`. The issue here is that we are relying on an invariant of `Arc` that isn't expressible in the borrow system since it isn't possible to statically tell if two `Arc`s are actually related, and it is only safe to extend the borrow of one to the lifetime of the other if they point to the same data.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this to fit the criteria of [hand-over-hand locking](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/concurrent-programming-with-chain-lockin/240149442).

```
use std::sync::Mutex;

fn main() {
    // Create a set of mutexes to lock hand-over-hand
    let mutexes = Vec::from_fn(4, |_| Mutex::new(false));

    // Lock the first one
    let val_0 = mutexes[0].lock();
    if !*val_0 {
        // Lock the second one
        let mut val_1 = mutexes[1].lock();
        // Unlock the first one
        drop(val_0);
        // Do logic
        *val_1 = true;
    }

    for mutex in mutexes.iter() {
        println!("{}" , *mutex.lock());
    }
}
```

**Edit #1**

> Does it work when access to lock n+1 is guarded by lock n?

If you mean something that could be shaped like the following, then I think the answer is no.

```
struct Level {
  data: bool,
  child: Option<Mutex<Box<Level>>>,
}
```

However, it is sensible that this **should not work**. When you wrap an object in a mutex, then you are saying "The entire object is safe". You can't say both "the entire pie is safe" and "I'm eating the stuff below the crust" at the same time. Perhaps you jettison the safety by creating a `Mutex<()>` and lock that?

Comment: Does the hand-over-hand locking work in a loop? Does it work when access to lock n+1 is guarded by lock n?

Comment: Maybe this "should not work", but I believe it's the standard way updates are done on concurrent linked lists, albeit with the guard (the bottom that lock a protects node b) as implicit. In those cases, I believe the mutex is indicating not "everything accessible through this lock is acquired exclusively by locking this mutex" but "everything accessible through this lock without acquiring any other locks is acquired exclusively by locking this mutex." Going the Mutex<()> route like you suggest leaves open the possibility of data races.

Comment: "The standard way" doesn't necessarily apply across languages with different paradigms ^_^. There's also the possibility that Rust is not able to express your particular concept in the safe portion of the language. Perhaps the solution you are seeking must be written in unsafe code that exposes a safe (because the programmer, not the compiler, has verified it) API.

Answer (score 2):

This is still not the answer your literal question of to how to do hand-over-hand locking, which should only be important in a concurrent setting (or if someone else forced you to use `Mutex` references to nodes). It is instead how to do this with `Rc` and `RefCell`, which you seem to be interested in.

`RefCell` only allows mutable writes when one mutable reference is held. Importantly, the `Rc<RefCell<Node>>` objects are *not* mutable references. The mutable references it is talking about are the results from calling `borrow_mut()` on the `Rc<RefCell<Node>>`object, and as long as you do that in a limited scope (e.g. the body of the while loop), you'll be fine.

The important thing happening in path compression is that the `next` Rc object will keep the rest of the chain alive while you swing the parent pointer for `node` to point at `root`. However, it is not a *reference* in the Rust sense of the word.

```
struct Node
{
    parent: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>
}

fn find_root(mut node: Rc<RefCell<Node>>) -> Rc<RefCell<Node>>
{
    while let Some(parent) = node.borrow().parent.clone()
    {
        node = parent;
    }

    return node;
}

fn path_compress(mut node: Rc<RefCell<Node>>, root: Rc<RefCell<Node>>)
{
    while node.borrow().parent.is_some()
    {
        let next = node.borrow().parent.clone().unwrap();
        node.borrow_mut().parent = Some(root.clone());
        node = next;
    }
}
```

This runs fine for me with the test harness I used, though there may still be bugs. It certainly compiles and runs without a `panic!` due to trying to `borrow_mut()` something that is already borrowed. It may actually produce the right answer, that's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

On IRC, Jonathan Reem pointed out that `inner` is borrowing until the end of its lexical scope, which is too far for what I was asking. Inlining it produces the following, which compiles without error:

```
fn find_root(x: Arc<Mutex<Node>>) -> Arc<Mutex<Node>> {
    let mut ans = x.clone();
    while ans.lock().parent.is_some() {
        ans = ans.lock().parent.clone().unwrap();
    }
    ans
}
```

**EDIT:** As Francis Gagné points out, this has a race condition, since the lock doesn't extend long enough. Here's a modified version that only has one `lock()` call; perhaps it is not vulnerable to the same problem.

```
fn find_root(x: Arc<Mutex<Node>>) -> Arc<Mutex<Node>> {
    let mut ans = x.clone();
    loop {
        ans = {
            let tmp = ans.lock();
            match tmp.parent.clone() {
               None => break,
               Some(z) => z
            }
        }
    }
    ans
}
```

**EDIT 2**: This only holds one lock at a time, and so is racey. I still don't know how to do hand-over-hand locking.

Comment: This is a dangerous usage pattern for `Mutex`: the value could change from another task between the first unlock and the second lock. For `RefCell` though, this pattern is fine, because there's no risk of a data race.

Comment: @FrancisGagné, good point. I'll add an edit to this answer pointing that out; I hope you'll tell me what you think of the other solution I'm about to add in my edit.

Comment: I'd remove the `.clone()` call on the `match` and change `Some(z) => z` to `Some(ref z) => z.clone()`; it avoids cloning the `Option` when it's a `None`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Frank Sherry and others, you shouldn't use Arc/Mutex when single threaded. But his code was outdated, so here is the new one (for version 1.0.0alpha2).
This does not take linear space either (like the recursive code given in the question).

```
struct Node {
    parent: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>
}

fn find_root(node: Rc<RefCell<Node>>) -> Rc<RefCell<Node>> {
    let mut ans = node.clone(); // Rc<RefCell<Node>>
    loop {
        ans = {
            let ans_ref = ans.borrow(); // std::cell::Ref<Node>
            match ans_ref.parent.clone() {
                None => break,
                Some(z) => z
            }
        } // ans_ref goes out of scope, and ans becomes mutable
    }
    ans
}

fn path_compress(mut node: Rc<RefCell<Node>>, root: Rc<RefCell<Node>>) {
    while node.borrow().parent.is_some() {
        let next = {
            let node_ref = node.borrow();
            node_ref.parent.clone().unwrap()
        };
        node.borrow_mut().parent = Some(root.clone());
        // RefMut<Node> from borrow_mut() is out of scope here...
        node = next; // therefore we can mutate node
    }
}
```

Note for beginners: Pointers are automatically dereferenced by dot operator. `ans.borrow()` actually means `(*ans).borrow()`. I intentionally used different styles for the two functions.

Answer (score -1):

Although not the answer to your literal question (hand-over locking), union-find with weighted-union and path-compression can be very simple in Rust:

```
fn unionfind<I: Iterator<(uint, uint)>>(mut iterator: I, nodes: uint) -> Vec<uint>
{
    let mut root = Vec::from_fn(nodes, |x| x);
    let mut rank = Vec::from_elem(nodes, 0u8);

    for (mut x, mut y) in iterator
    {
        // find roots for x and y; do path compression on look-ups
        while (x != root[x]) { root[x] = root[root[x]]; x = root[x]; }
        while (y != root[y]) { root[y] = root[root[y]]; y = root[y]; }

        if x != y
        {
            // weighted union swings roots
            match rank[x].cmp(&rank[y])
            {
                Less    => root[x] = y,
                Greater => root[y] = x,
                Equal   =>
                {
                    root[y] = x; 
                    rank[x] += 1 
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe the meta-point is that the union-find algorithm may not be the best place to handle node ownership, and by using references to existing memory (in this case, by just using uint identifiers for the nodes) without affecting the lifecycle of the nodes makes for a much simpler implementation, if you can get away with it of course.

Comment: This doesn't allow forgotten nodes to be deallocated until the whole arena is deallocated. It also doesn't answer the question of hand-over-hand locking in other cases like concurrent linked lists.

Comment: Well, neither does the C code you presented. It was hard to tell if your question was about solving a problem (union find) or exploring a programming pattern. You've now made it clearer.