# traverse a linked structure releasing locks after acquiring the next one

Tags: rust

I want to traverse a tree (but it may as well be a linked list) with one lock per node. The idea is to find the id of the next node from the current, and lock it **before** unlocking the current. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to make the borrow checker happy. I tried writing an example of what I think the code could look like. ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0623edb37c2a99f625f3b83055a1eb18))

Before the example, I should say that I found a way to make this work by using the [rental](https://crates.io/crates/rental) crate, and making `current` be a self referential struct that holds both the `Arc` and the mutex guard inside it (so there is no borrows anymore). What I was wondering is if there is some more rust-idiomatic way of doing this without bringing that dependency. (Or perhaps some really short `unsafe` code?)

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, MutexGuard};

fn main() {
    let mut current: Arc<Mutex<Content>> = get(0);
    let mut current_lock: MutexGuard<Content> = current.lock().unwrap();
    // this should loop 4
    loop {
        let next_node = match *current_lock {
            Content::Next(id) => get(id),
            Content::Terminal => {
                return;
            }
        };
        // acquire the next lock
        let next_lock = next_node.lock().unwrap();
        // release the previous (but after having acquired the new one)
        drop(current_lock);
        // do the same for the next one
        // (but this won't compile)
        current = next_node;
        current_lock = next_lock;
    }
}

fn get(id: u32) -> Arc<Mutex<Content>> {
    // 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> end
    Arc::new(Mutex::new(if id == 4 {
        Content::Terminal
    } else {
        Content::Next(id + 1)
    }))
}

enum Content {
    Next(u32),
    Terminal,
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Hand-over-hand locking with Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27337939/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.